# How to split all posts by their day?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm noob in django, so I am facing with problem which all posts should divided by day

**For example**:

`db.sqlite3 > posts_post`

| id | name | pub_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | My awesome name | 2023-04-23 09:21:24.3921 |
| 2 | This is a great title | 2023-04-23 09:22:56.7981 |
| 3 | Another great title | 2023-04-24 18:23:34.3123 |
| 4 | Different name here | 2023-04-25 17:45:21.9643 |
| 5 | Just a few words | 2023-04-25 18:04:32.1236 |

Then, I should get result like that:

```py
>>> [ [Post(1), Post(2)], [Post(3)], [Post(4), Post(5)] ]
```

As you can see on result I should get a list that contains lists. In that lists there are only posts whose days are the same. In post 1 and 2, day - 23, so they are together, post 3 is the only post whose day is 24. Same goes for post 4 and 5. Please help me to tackle this problem

Answer (score 4):

You can use QuerySet and itertools.groupby(). Something like this:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate
from itertools import groupby
...
def group_posts_by_day(request):
    posts = Post.objects.annotate(pub_day=TruncDate('pub_date')).order_by('pub_day')
    grouped_posts = []
    for _, group in groupby(posts, key=lambda post: post.pub_day):
        grouped_posts.append(list(group))
    return grouped_posts
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple one-liner with [**`itertools.groupby(…)`** <sup>[python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

[
    list(vs)
    for __, vs in groupby(
        Post.objects.order_by('pub_date'), lambda post: post.pub_date.date()
    )
]
```

or if you want to use a dictionary that maps the date to a list of values:

```
from itertools import groupby

{
    k: list(vs)
    for k, vs in groupby(
        Post.objects.order_by('pub_date'), lambda post: post.pub_date.date()
    )
}
```

inside each list, the items are still grouped in chronological order, even if these thus have the same date.